# Localuser logon powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication

```
New-LocalGroup -Name 'Group01' -Description 'group01'
New-LocalUser -Name "User11" -Description "User." -NoPassword
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Group01" -Member User11
Enable-LocalUser -Name "User11"
```

How do I make the localuser able to be logon to in windows? It doesn't appear as a user to switch accounts. It shows as being enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user need to be in "Users", "Guests" or "Administrators" group (or even some other defaults, but not in personal groups) in order to open a session. You can use personal groups to define some security.

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member User11
```

The other way is to set the privilege of open an interactive session with gpedit.msc and add your personal group (I think the first way is better).